# Foreach for array

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have an array which I populate like so

```
var list = [];

featureLayer.queryFeatures(querySnTR)
            .then((result) => {
                                
                   result.attachmentInfos.forEach((x) => {
                   list.push(uriString + "/" + x.id);
                  });
                });
console.log("list", list);
```

I print out the `list` with `console.log` and it returns values inside.
[image]

Afterwards I do a `foreach` to go through all the elements inside and create a `div` for each of them. The thing is, it doesn't even go in the `foreach` function.

```
list.forEach((x) => {
    console.log("CL", list);
    console.log("x element", x);

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = x;
    image.className = "queryImg";
    document.getElementById("queryResults").appendChild(image);
  });
```

It doesn't print out `CL` or `x element` for that matter.
Any ideas as to why?

The whole original code, for reference

```
startup: function () {

                var _that = this;
                _this = _that;

                this.map.on("click", function (e) {
                    _this.map.graphics.clear();

                    identifyTask = new IdentifyTask("https://server/arcgis/rest/services/MUNICIPALITY_BUNDLE/ZK_KATASTAR_NA_ZELENILO/MapServer");

                    identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters();
                    identifyParams.tolerance = 10;
                    identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
                    identifyParams.layerIds = [1];
                    identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
                    identifyParams.width = _this.map.width;
                    identifyParams.height = _this.map.height;
                    identifyParams.spatialReference = _this.map.spatialReference;

                    identifyParams.geometry = e.mapPoint;
                    identifyParams.mapExtent = _this.map.extent;

                    identifyTask.execute(identifyParams).then(function (data) {
                        objId = data[0].feature.attributes.objectid;

                        const querySnTR = {
                            where: "1 = 1",
                            outFields: ["*"]
                        };

                        var uriString = "https://server/arcgis/rest/services/MUNICIPALITY_BUNDLE/ZK_KATASTAR_NA_ZELENILO/MapServer/101/" + objId + "/attachments";
                        var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(uriString);

                        featureLayer.queryFeatures(querySnTR)
                            .then((result) => {

                                result.attachmentInfos.forEach((x) => {
                                    list.push(uriString + "/" + x.id);
                                });
                            });

                        const myFunction = async () => {
                            const { attachmentInfos } = await featureLayer.queryFeatures(querySnTR);
                            const list = attachmentInfos.map(({ id }) => `${uriString}/${id}`);
                            console.log("list", list);
                            list.forEach((x) => {
                                var image = document.createElement("img");
                                image.src = x;
                                image.className = "queryImg";
                                document.getElementById("queryResults").appendChild(image);
                            });
                        };
                    });
                });
            }
```

Comment: No, the array is not populated. The array is populated after your `queryFeatures`. Where do you call `queryFeatures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a trick on how the console works.
When you are executing the log the list is empty (100% sure) because you are populating it asynchronously. But the console has the reference to it and it will print it afterwards.
That's why your list is empty. You need to handle asynchrony here. You could work with an async/await approach or using promises, that will depend on the rest of your code, this is an example of how to do it with an async function (and rewritted it to modern javascript):

```js
const myFunction = async () => {
  const {attachmentInfos} = await featureLayer.queryFeatures(querySnTR);
  const list = attachmentInfos.map(({id}) => `${uriString}/${id}`);
  console.log("list", list);
  list.forEach((x) => {
    // put your code here
  });
};
```

Edited:
Now that you share all your code you can simply do:

```js
featureLayer.queryFeatures(querySnTR)
  .then((result) => {                              
      result.attachmentInfos.forEach((attachmentInfo) => {
        var x = uriString + "/" + attachmentInfo.id
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = x;
        image.className = "queryImg";
        document.getElementById("queryResults").appendChild(image);
     });
});
```

I would recommend you also to give vars meaningful names, not `x` but `attachmentInfo`, etc...

Comment: So I have added the entire function where this is supposed to occur. Should I remove my `featureLayer.queryFeatures` function?

Comment: I have edited my code according to your last update, you don't need to do anything weird, why not just in the callback of the queryFeatures do all the manipulation you need?